# Pyinstaller scrapy error:

Tags: python, windows-7, pyinstaller, scrapy

After installing all dependencies for scrapy on windows 32bit. I've tried to build an executable from my scrapy spider. Spider script "runspider.py" works ok when running as "python runspider.py"

Building executable "pyinstaller --onefile runspider.py":

> C:\Users\username\Documents\scrapyexe>pyinstaller --onefile
>   runspider.py 19 INFO: wrote
>   C:\Users\username\Documents\scrapyexe\runspider.spec 49 INFO: Testing
>   for ability to set icons, version resources... 59 INFO: ... resource
>   update available 59 INFO: UPX is not available. 89 INFO: Processing
>   hook hook-os 279 INFO: Processing hook hook-time 279 INFO: Processing
>   hook hook-cPickle 380 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre 561 INFO:
>   Processing hook hook-cStringIO 700 INFO: Processing hook
>   hook-encodings 720 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs 1351 INFO:
>   Extending PYTHONPATH with C:\Users\username\Documents\scrapyexe 1351
>   INFO: checking Analysis 1351 INFO: building Analysis because
>   out00-Analysis.toc non existent 1351 INFO: running Analysis
>   out00-Analysis.toc 1351 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT to dependent
>   assemblies of final executable
>
> 1421 INFO: Searching for assembly
>   x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21
>   022.8_none ... 1421 INFO: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc
>   8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91.manifest 1421 INFO:
>   Searching for file msvcr90.dll 1421 INFO: Found file
>   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_
>   9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\msvcr90.dll 1421 INFO: Searching for file msvcp90.dll 1421 INFO: Found file
>   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_
>   9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\msvcp90.dll 1421 INFO: Searching for file msvcm90.dll 1421 INFO: Found file
>   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_
>   9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\msvcm90.dll 1592 INFO: Analyzing C:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader_pyi_boots trap.py
>   1621 INFO: Processing hook hook-os 1661 INFO: Processing hook
>   hook-site 1681 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings 1872 INFO:
>   Processing hook hook-time 1872 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle 1983
>   INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre 2173 INFO: Processing hook
>   hook-cStringIO 2332 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs 2963 INFO:
>   Processing hook hook-pydoc 3154 INFO: Processing hook hook-email 3255
>   INFO: Processing hook hook-httplib 3305 INFO: Processing hook
>   hook-email.message 3444 INFO: Analyzing
>   C:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_import ers.py
>   3535 INFO: Analyzing
>   C:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_archiv e.py 3615
>   INFO: Analyzing
>   C:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_carchi ve.py 3684
>   INFO: Analyzing
>   C:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_os_pat h.py 3694
>   INFO: Analyzing runspider.py 3755 WARNING: No django root directory
>   could be found! 3755 INFO: Processing hook hook-django 3785 INFO:
>   Processing hook hook-lxml.etree 4135 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml
>   4196 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml.dom 4246 INFO: Processing hook
>   hook-xml.sax 4296 INFO: Processing hook hook-pyexpat 4305 INFO:
>   Processing hook hook-xml.dom.domreg 4736 INFO: Processing hook
>   hook-pywintypes 5046 INFO: Processing hook hook-distutils 7750 INFO:
>   Hidden import 'codecs' has been found otherwise 7750 INFO: Hidden
>   import 'encodings' has been found otherwise 7750 INFO: Looking for
>   run-time hooks 7750 INFO: Analyzing rthook
>   C:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rth
>   ooks\pyi_rth_twisted.py 8111 INFO: Analyzing rthook
>   C:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rth
>   ooks\pyi_rth_django.py 8121 INFO: Processing hook hook-django.core
>   8131 INFO: Processing hook hook-django.core.management 8401 INFO:
>   Processing hook hook-django.core.mail 8862 INFO: Processing hook
>   hook-django.db 9112 INFO: Processing hook hook-django.db.backends 9153
>   INFO: Processing hook hook-django.db.backends.mysql 9163 INFO:
>   Processing hook hook-django.db.backends.mysql.base 9163 INFO:
>   Processing hook hook-django.db.backends.oracle 9183 INFO: Processing
>   hook hook-django.db.backends.oracle.base 9253 INFO: Processing hook
>   hook-django.core.cache 9874 INFO: Processing hook hook-sqlite3 10023
>   INFO: Processing hook hook-django.contrib 10023 INFO: Processing hook
>   hook-django.contrib.sessions 11887 INFO: Using Python library
>   C:\Windows\system32\python27.dll 12226 INFO: Warnings written to
>   C:\Users\username\Documents\scrapyexe\build\runspid
>   er\warnrunspider.txt 12256 INFO: checking PYZ 12256 INFO: rebuilding
>   out00-PYZ.toc because out00-PYZ.pyz is missing 12256 INFO: building
>   PYZ (ZlibArchive) out00-PYZ.toc 16983 INFO: checking PKG 16993 INFO:
>   rebuilding out00-PKG.toc because out00-PKG.pkg is missing 16993 INFO:
>   building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg 19237 INFO: checking EXE 19237
>   INFO: rebuilding out00-EXE.toc because runspider.exe missing 19237
>   INFO: building EXE from out00-EXE.toc 19237 INFO: Appending archive to
>   EXE C:\Users\username\Documents\scrapyexe\dist\run spider.exe

running built exe "runspider.exe":

> C:\Users\username\Documents\scrapyexe\dist>runspider.exe
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 2, in
>
> File "C:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line
>   270, in load_module
>
> exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File "C:\Users\username\Documents\scrapyexe\build\runspider\out00-PYZ.pyz\scrapy"
>   , line 10, in
>
> File "C:\Users\username\Documents\scrapyexe\build\runspider\out00-PYZ.pyz\pkgutil
>   ", line 591, in get_data
>
> File "C:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line
>    342, in get_data
>
> fp = open(path, 'rb')
>
> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\
>   \Temp\_MEI15522\scrapy\VERSION'

I'm extremely helpful for any kind of help. I need to know how to build standalone exe from scrapy spider for windows.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Inside `scrapy/__init__.py`, you'll see the part where the author uses `pkgutil.get_data()`. I'm  not very sure if you need to indicate to pyinstaller that the scrapy/VERSION text file gets packaged altogether like a data file, or if pkgutil.get_data works at all for pyinstaller, but heres a quick hack I used.

Simply go to the `__init__.py` file, comment away these 2 lines and replace with a string of your choice e.g `__version__="scrap-123"`. You will need `__version__` as it's being referred to in another module.

```
__version__ = pkgutil.get_data(__package__, 'VERSION').decode('ascii').strip()
version_info = tuple(int(v) if v.isdigit() else v
                     for v in __version__.split('.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a scrapy folder under the same directory as runspider.exe (the exe file generated by pyinstaller).

Then copy the "VERSION" and "mime.types" files(default path: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\scrapy`) to the scrapy you just created in the scrappy folder you create . (If you only copy "VERSION", you will be prompted to find the "mime.types" file)