# Python Scrapy conversion to EXE file using PyInstaller

Tags: python, scrapy, pyinstaller

I am trying to convert a Scrapy script to an EXE file.
The *main.py* file looks like this:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from amazon.spiders.amazon_scraper import Spider

spider = Spider()
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
    'FEED_URI': 'data.csv',
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3,
    'RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY': True,
    'ROTATING_PROXY_LIST_PATH': 'proxies.txt',
    'USER_AGENT_LIST': 'useragents.txt',
    'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES' :
    {
        'rotating_proxies.middlewares.RotatingProxyMiddleware': 610,
        'rotating_proxies.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620,
        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
        'random_useragent.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400
    }
})

process.crawl(spider)
process.start() # The script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

The Scrapy script looks like any other. I am using `pyinstaller.exe --onefile main.py` to convert it to an EXE file. When I try to open the *main.exe* file inside the dist folder it starts outputting errors:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '...\\scrapy\\VERSION'
```

I can fix it by creating a scrapy folder inside the dist folder and uploading a VERSION file from lib/site-packages/scrapy.
After that, many other errors occur but I can fix them by uploading some scrapy libraries.

In the end, it starts outputting an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.mime'
```

I don’t even know what it means. I have never seen it.

I am using:

- Python 3.6.5
- Scrapy 1.5.0
- PyInstaller 3.3.1

Comment: see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557693/pyinstaller-scrapy-error

Answer (score 3):

I had the same situation. 
Instead of trying to make PyInstaller count this file (I failed all my attempts to do it), I decided to check and change some part of Scrapy code in order to avoid this error.

I noticed that there is only one place where the [\scrapy\VERSION](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/VERSION) file is used—[\scrapy\**init**.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/__init__.py#L9-L13) 
I decided to hardcode that value from *scrapy\version* by changing *scrapy_*init*_.py*:

```
#import pkgutil
__version__ = "1.5.0" #pkgutil.get_data(__package__, 'VERSION').decode('ascii').strip()
version_info = tuple(int(v) if v.isdigit() else v
                     for v in __version__.split('.'))
#del pkgutil
```

After this change, there isn't any need to store the version in an external file.
As there isn't any reference to \scrapy\version file, that error will not occur.

After that, I had the same `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]` with [\scrapy\mime.types](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/mime.types) file. 
There is the same situation with file *\scrapy\mime.types*. It is used only in file [\scrapy\responsetypes.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/responsetypes.py#L35-L41).

```
...
#from pkgutil import get_data
...
    def __init__(self):
        self.classes = {}
        self.mimetypes = MimeTypes()
        #mimedata = get_data('scrapy', 'mime.types').decode('utf8')
        mimedata = """
        Copypaste all 750 lines of \scrapy\mime.types here
"""
        self.mimetypes.readfp(StringIO(mimedata))
        for mimetype, cls in six.iteritems(self.CLASSES):
            self.classes[mimetype] = load_object(cls)
```

This change resolved `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]` with \scrapy\mime.types file.
I agree that hardcoding 750 lines of text into Python code is not the best decision.

After that, I started to receive `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named scrapy.spiderloader`. I added `"scrapy.spiderloader"` into the hidden imports parameter of pyinstaller.

Next Issue: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named scrapy.statscollectors`.

The final version of the PyInstaller command for my Scrapy script consists of 46 hidden imports. After that, I received a working EXE file.